# Failed to update Help for the module

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Update-Help

Update-Help : Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'WindowsUpdateProvider'
with UI culture(s) {en-US} : Unable to retrieve the HelpInfo XML file for UI
culture en-US. Make sure the HelpInfoUri property in the module manifest is
valid or check your network connection and then try the  command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Help
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Update-Help], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToRetrieveHelpInfoXml,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.UpdateHelpCommand

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: gz. What is the question?

Comment: The question is: Why is OP receiving the error when running Update-Help?

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below, sometimes there's no XML document to update.

```
Update-Help -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Official link to Microsoft: [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/updateing-powershell-user-help-files/07afd880-c543-4e56-9446-1e9eb509003d)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/updateing-powershell-user-help-files/07afd880-c543-4e56-9446-1e9eb509003d)

*Apparently a problem at Microsoft's end it always happens since sometimes there's no XML document to update, so for the time being use this command:*

```
Update-Help -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```